# I can't deploy my web service

Tags: web-services

java.lang.LinkageError: You are loading old SAAJ from jar:file:/C:/dev/wrks/wrk_iris_2/IRISBuild/iris_lib_runtime/orabpel.jar!/javax/xml/soap/MessageFactory.class

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 2):

Remove axis-saaj-1.4.jar and Redeploy your server.

Comment: This worked for me, but I don't understand why. Could you explain why this works? I'm guessing, there is a default SAAJ that will be used if axis-saaj-1.4.jar is deleted?

Comment: It's works for me too. I remove _axis jar_ and _saaj jar_ from my build path....